# Table within a table

Tags: html, html-table

I'm writing a code for the following table (I have to use table inside table)

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<body>

<table>

        <table border=1 cellspacing=0 width="250px">
            <tr>
                <td width=20%>1</td>
                <td width=20%>2</td>
                <td width=20%>3</td>
                <td width=20%>4</td>
                <td width=20%>5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table border=1 cellspacing=0 width="250px">
            <tr>
                <td width=60%>6</td>
                <td width=20%>7</td>
                <td width=20%>8</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table border=1 cellspacing=0 width="250px">
            <tr>
                <td width=20%>9</td>
                <td width=20%>10</td>
                <td width=20%>11</td>
                <td width=20% rowspan=2>12</td>
                <td width=20%>13</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>17</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

But in browser I'm getting something different, looking like this :

[image]

I'm very beginner with HTML, I'm trying to understand how tables within tables work mostly by doing exercises for that.

Comment: `table` is not a valid child of `tr` (depending on the browser the inner `table` would then just be moved out of the `tr` and would be placed behind of the surrounding `table`) .  Only `th` and `td` are valid as child of `tr`. Why do you need `table` inside of a `table`? The structure above can be create using `colspan` and `rowspan`.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks. I've updated without `<tr>` and the result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished with one table:

**HTML**

```
<table border=1 >
    <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                <td colspan="3">6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>11</td>
                <td rowspan=2>12</td>
                <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>17</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/HcRW3/

Comment: Thanks for this, but the point of this exercise is to use tables within tables, not just one table.

Comment: @user3002211 I would respectively argue that your exercise is flawed and is teaching you to master a bad practice.

Comment: @KevinBowersox This is sadly still not a rare situation in schools or courses. And even apparently _specialist books_ have such flaws.

Answer (score 1):

your rowspan in the 3rd row can't work as the table has only one row. It doesn't know anything about the outside table.

I really can't understand why you have to go with table in table, but if you must, the outer table can only have 3 rows and the 3rd nested table has two rows.

Answer (score 1):

May I advise you use colspan and Rowspan instead of tables inside tables it much easier and how I do most of my tables which require cells to be merged.

You can find an example of colspan here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

and an example of rowspan: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Here is an example of the code to do this:

```
<table border="1">
         <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td >3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">6</td>
    <td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td >11</td>
<td rowspan="2">12</td>
<td>13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td >15</td>
<td >16</td>
<td>17</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am aware of that, however this exercise requires to be solved using tables within tables..

Comment: Tables within tables is bad practice and not needed when you can just span across cols/rows with built in functions.

Answer (score 1):

May well work better for you:

```
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: none;">12</td>
        <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td style="border-top: none;"></td>
        <td>17</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but just an extension to my comment, to explain the result.

`table` is not a valid child of `tr`,  only `th` and `td` are valid as child of `tr`.

For most browsers the behavior if they detect an invalide child inside of an element is, to move the child after that element. This is repeated until the structure is valid.
Because `table` is neither a valid child of `tr` nor of `table` the innter tables are all moved outside of the surrounding table. The resulting structure the browsers most likely creates out of your original code of the question:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
         <table border=1 cellspacing=0>
             <tr>
                 <td width=20%>1</td>
                 <td width=20%>2</td>
                 <td width=20%>3</td>
                 <td width=20%>4</td>
                 <td width=20%>5</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
   </tr>
   <tr>
         <table border=1 cellspacing=0>
             <tr>
                 <td width=60%>6</td>
                 <td width=20%>7</td>
                 <td width=20%>8</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
   </tr>
   <tr>
         <table border=1 cellspacing=0>
             <tr>
                 <td width=20%>9</td>
                 <td width=20%>10</td>
                 <td width=20%>11</td>
                 <td width=20% rowspan=2>12</td>
                 <td width=20%>13</td>
             </tr>
         </table>

   </tr>
   <tr>
         <table border=1 cellspacing=0>
             <tr>
                 <td>14</td>
                 <td>15</td>
                 <td>16</td>
                 <td>17</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

would then be:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   </tr>
 </table>

 <table border=1 cellspacing=0>
     <tr>
         <td width=20%>1</td>
         <td width=20%>2</td>
         <td width=20%>3</td>
         <td width=20%>4</td>
         <td width=20%>5</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
 <table border=1 cellspacing=0>
     <tr>
         <td width=60%>6</td>
         <td width=20%>7</td>
         <td width=20%>8</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
 <table border=1 cellspacing=0>
     <tr>
         <td width=20%>9</td>
         <td width=20%>10</td>
         <td width=20%>11</td>
         <td width=20% rowspan=2>12</td>
         <td width=20%>13</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
 <table border=1 cellspacing=0>
     <tr>
         <td>14</td>
         <td>15</td>
         <td>16</td>
         <td>17</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should be able to do this in one table. Like this,

```
        <table border=1 cellspacing=0>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan=3>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>11</td>
                <tdrowspan=2>12</td>
                <td>13</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>17</td>
            </tr>
       </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try not to put a table inside a table. "Rowspan" and "colspan" are a good idea. You'd probably want to use 'valign' top (vertical align) to make sure the 12 stays on the same level as the row.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td rowspan="2" valign="top">12</td>
        <td>13</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>17</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```